# Flask eventlet Dispatchermiddleware SSL

Tags: python, flask, ssl, eventlet, python-socketio

I have this `Python` code and i want to use `SSL` for the connection.

```py
import socketio
from eventlet import listen, wrap_ssl
from eventlet.wsgi import server
from flask import Flask
from werkzeug.middleware.dispatcher import DispatcherMiddleware


app = Flask(__name__)
app1 = Flask(__name__)


sio = socketio.Server(async_mode="eventlet")


app.wsgi_app = socketio.WSGIApp(sio, DispatcherMiddleware(app, {"/app1": app1}))


server(listen(("localhost", 80)), app)
```

Below are my `Python` and `Package` version details:

```py
Python 3.10.7 64-bit
python-socketio==5.8.0
eventlet==0.33.3
Flask==2.3.1
Werkzeug==2.3.0
```

Update 26.06:

After some searching on google and reading the documentation from `eventlet`. I have a new version of the code.

```py
import socketio
from eventlet import listen
from eventlet.wsgi import server
from flask import Flask
from werkzeug.middleware.dispatcher import DispatcherMiddleware


app = Flask(__name__)
app1 = Flask(__name__)


sio = socketio.Server(async_mode="eventlet")


app.wsgi_app = socketio.WSGIApp(sio, DispatcherMiddleware(app, {"/app1": app1}))


server(wrap_ssl(listen(("127.0.0.1", 443)), certfile='MyCert.crt', keyfile='MyPrivate.key'), app)
```

But now i get the following error.

```
(17524) wsgi starting up on https://127.0.0.1:443
(17524) accepted ('127.0.0.1', 62260)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\eventlet\hubs\selects.py", line 59, in wait    
    listeners.get(fileno, hub.noop).cb(fileno)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\eventlet\greenthread.py", line 221, in main    
    result = function(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\eventlet\wsgi.py", line 837, in process_request
    proto.__init__(conn_state, self)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\eventlet\wsgi.py", line 350, in __init__       
    self.handle()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\eventlet\wsgi.py", line 383, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\eventlet\wsgi.py", line 412, in handle_one_request
    self.raw_requestline = self._read_request_line()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\eventlet\wsgi.py", line 395, in _read_request_line
    return self.rfile.readline(self.server.url_length_limit)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\socket.py", line 705, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\eventlet\green\ssl.py", line 253, in recv_into
    return self._base_recv(nbytes, flags, into=True, buffer_=buffer)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\eventlet\green\ssl.py", line 268, in _base_recv
    read = self.read(nbytes, buffer_)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\eventlet\green\ssl.py", line 187, in read
    return self._call_trampolining(
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\eventlet\green\ssl.py", line 162, in _call_trampolining
    return func(*a, **kw)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\ssl.py", line 1130, in read
    return self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_CERTIFICATE_UNKNOWN] sslv3 alert certificate unknown (_ssl.c:2548)
Removing descriptor: 852
```

Comment: You are using the eventlet web server. They have documentation on how to add SSL: https://eventlet.net/doc/modules/wsgi.html#ssl